# React router private route not getting props from state (e.g. authentication state)

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm trying to implement a private route component to redirect users that are not authenticated. The problem is when I render the component like `<PrivateRoute authenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path='/private' component={Panel} currentUser={this.state.currentUser}`, the private route redirects the authenticated users to the login page, instead of going to the panel.

In `App.js` I render all the routes, including `<PrivateRoute/>`, and I set the `currentUser` and `isAuthenticated` state variables in `ComponentDidMount()`, but I can't pass them to `PrivateRoute`.

**App.js**

```js
//imports...
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        currentUser: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false
    }

    loadCurrentUser = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
        });
        // imported method
        getCurrentUser()
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    currentUser: response,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    isLoading: false
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false
                });  
            });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  handleLogin = () => {
        this.loadCurrentUser();
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navigation
                    currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
                    isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute
                        authenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                        exact
                        path='/postulante'
                        component={Panel}
                        currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path='/'
                        render={
                            (props) => <Landing {...props} />
                        } />

                    <Route
                        path="/login"
                        exact
                        render={
                            (props) =>  <Login onLogin={this.handleLogin} {...props} />
                        } />
                </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Note that the `<Navigation />` component does get the state variables right.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```js
//imports...
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authenticated ? (
          <Component {...rest} {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
);
export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: Hi ! Just wrote you a solution and a sandbox for your reference. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with the `PrivateRoute` component rendering the first-time without any updated props from the main App component.

If you were to navigate directly to the `PrivateRoute` path without first going into any other Route, you will be redirected back to `/login`. Your `PrivateRoute` tries to render before the parent App's `componentDidMount()` logic completes. So isAuthenticated is passed as false.

The opposite would occur if you start in lets say `Home` or `Login`, and you use a `Link` to go to the `PrivateRoute`.

Ultimately, this is why people use a state-management tool like redux to have the authenticated-state be shared globally instead of being passed through parent-components.

**Although there is a workaround!**

See sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dan-uskcy

1. We can workaround this by using an additional state-value to check
   whether the App component was ever intialized. We'll call this
   `wasInitialized`
2. PrivateRoute will receive that as prop called wasInitialized, and if
   we go directly to its component-path, `wasInitialized` will be false until App has a chance to complete its `componentDidMount()` logic.
3. If wasInitialized is falsey, we will not Redirect to /login,
   instead we will just display an empty-string, giving the parent App's
   `componentDidMount()` time to execute and update the
   `isAuthenticated` value.
4. So now lets take a look at this line:

   `<Route {...rest} render={props => auth === true ? <Component
   {...props} /> : !wasInitialized ?  ""  :  <Redirect to="/login" />
   }`

   In the next re-render, `isAuthenticated` will be either true or
   false. If the user isAuthenticated, we render the expected component. If the user is not authenticated, we go to the next check. Now wasInitialized will have a value of true, so that check evaluates to false. Thus, since both checks do not pass, we redirect to `/login`.

### App.js

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    currentUser: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isLoading: false,
    wasInitialized: false
}

loadCurrentUser = () => {
this.setState({
  isLoading: true
    });
    // imported method
    getCurrentUser()
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                currentUser: response,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                wasInitialized: true,
                isLoading: false
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                wasInitialized: true
            });  
        });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  handleLogin = () => {
        this.loadCurrentUser();
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
render () {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navigation
                currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
                isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                    authenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    path='/postulante'
                    component={Panel}
                    wasInitialized={this.state.wasInitialized}
                    currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
                <Route
                    exact
                    path='/'
                    render={
                        (props) => <Landing {...props} />
                    } />

                <Route
                    path="/login"
                    exact
                    render={
                        (props) =>  <Login onLogin={this.handleLogin} {...props} />
                    } />
            </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

### Private

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth,
  wasInitialized,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        auth === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : !wasInitialized ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but I didn't know how to make a workaround. Thank you! Btw, in the solution, App.js should have wasInitialized in the state.